# Sympy Substitution on the output of variable

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

In my code I have a variable *h* set to an integration. I would like to perform a coordinate change on the output of that integration. Using a computer algebra software like Maple this is achieved by substituting the coordinate change into the variable *h*, where the substitution takes place on the output of the integration. I tried the following code:

```
import sympy as sp

r = sym.Symbol('r')
R = sym.Symbol('R')
theta00 = sp.pi*sp.exp(-(r**2-1)/2)

h = sp.integrate((r**2/2)*sp.diff(theta00, r), (r, -sp.oo, R))
hxy = h.subs(sp.sqrt((x-1)**2 + y**2), R)
```

The output of *hxy* is the same as the output of *h*, without the required substitution. I think the substitution is being applied before the integration. Is there a way to work with the output of the integration in the variable *h*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the veariables you are using are sympy symbols. Here I am using the symbols from `sympy.abc` directly.

Then for the substitution you can create use a dictionary mapping variables in your formulas to the substituted value.

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import r, R, x, y
theta00 = sp.pi*sp.exp(-(r**2-1)/2)
h = sp.integrate((r**2/2)*sp.diff(theta00, r), (r, -sp.oo, R))
```

[image]

```py
hxy = h.subs({R: sp.sqrt((x-1)**2 + y**2)})
```

[image]

You could also replace by a numeric value

```py
h.subs({R: 3})
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer! My apologies, I noticed my error shortly after posting. The error was actually more simple, I had the expression and substituted expression the wrong way around in ```subs()``` (as we can see in your substitution).  Of course x and y were declared as symbolic variables higher up in the worksheet, I forgot to copy them over.

Comment: Thank your comment, now you can accept the answer please, check [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more details.